# Pass Data from Middleware to _Layout View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

My asp.net-core Application has a sidebar in _Layout.cshtml. The sidebar is dynamically, so I need PageData. I tryed to pass the PageData from my PagesMiddleware to the View (I don't want to forward the PageData in every Controller for the Views).

---

Don´t want this: [PagesMiddleware] -> Controller -> _Layout.cshtml

PagesMiddleware: `context.Items.Add("pages", pages);`

every Controller: `ViewData["Pages"] = TempData["pages"];`

_Layout: `@ViewData["Pages"]`

---

Is there something like this: [PagesMiddleware] ->  -> _Layout.cshtml

PagesMiddleware: `ViewData["Pages"] = pages;`

_Layout: `@ViewData["Pages"]`

---

PageData can be a string. How can i pass a string from Middleware to _Layout View without extra (redundant) Code in all Controllers?

Comment: In razor views you [have access](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-2.2#use-httpcontext-from-a-razor-view) to HttpContext object, so to HttpContext.Items... you can always disregard controller part.

Comment: Post your Comment as Answer, I will mark it as solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per comment on the post, HttpContext object is always [accessible](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context#use-httpcontext-from-a-razor-view) from a Razor view

**Middleware**

```
context.Items.Add("pages", pages);
```

**View**

```
@{
    var pages = Context.Items["pages"];
}
```